# Retrieving Raw RTF from RichTextBox (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am essentially creating a text editor utilizing the RichTextBox control. I am storing raw richtext on my SQL Database for each specific "message". When displaying my message on my RichTextBox control I am able to pull in a string of the raw RTF, place it inside a FlowDocument and assign the current FlowDocument displayed, keeping all of the different fontsizes, bolding, italics, etc. via this method and it seems to be working well:

```
public static FlowDocument ToFlowDocument(string text)
{
    var result = new FlowDocument();
    var textrange = new TextRange(result.ContentStart, result.ContentEnd);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text ?? string.Empty)))
    {
       textRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am able to load the formatted RTF into the FlowDocument/RichTextBox -- now I want to retrieve the raw RTF from the FlowDocument and then be able to store this back into my database after the user has edited the message. All examples I find are saving the rtf into an RTF file - that is not what I wish to do.

Currently I am trying to utilize:

```
internal void RefreshMessageText(FlowDocument document)
{
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
    Application.Current.Dispather.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            tr.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
         }
    }));

    this.MessageText = tr.Text;
}
```

However, this is simply retrieving me the plain text. There are no fontsizes saved, no bolding tags, italic tags, etc.

The type of string I would like to retrieve to store in my DB looks like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs21\f2\cf0 \cf0\q1{\f2 {\ltrch Test }{\fs36\ltrch Text}\line{\fs36\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\q1\par}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamReader` to create an asynchronous solution to convert the stream buffer to the original `string` without potentially freezing the UI:

```cs
internal async Task RefreshMessageTextAsync(FlowDocument document)
{
  var documentRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
  await using Stream destinationStream = new MemoryStream();
  documentRange.Save(destinationStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
  _ = stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

  // Use a different constructor overload 
  // in case you need to specify the encoding of the stream data
  using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
  string rtfText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

  this.MessageText = rtfText;
}
```

In case you really need to enqueue the operation to the `Dispatcher` you should consider to call `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` configured with a `DispatcherPriority` as low as possible to relief the `Dispatcher` and avoid blocking (further improve performance):

```cs
internal async Task RefreshMessageTextAsync(FlowDocument document)
{  
  this.MessageText = await await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    async () => await ConvertDocumentToRtfAsync(document), 
    DispatcherPriority.Background);
}

private async Task<string> ConvertDocumentToRtfAsync(FlowDocument document)
{
  var documentRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
  await using Stream destinationStream = new MemoryStream();
  documentRange.Save(destinationStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
  _ = stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

  // Use a different constructor overload 
  // in case you need to specify the encoding of the stream data
  using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
  string rtfText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

  return rtfText;
}
```